# Coluna tipo Lista

Tags: sql-server

Trabalhei muito tempo com o PostgreSQL e agora com o SQL Server tenho sentido falta de algumas características que facilitavam muito a vida.
Tenho por exemplo uma tabela que uma de suas colunas deve ser uma lista de *strings*, ou seja, um *array* de *varchar* (no postgre era tudo muito simples):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    id         integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name       varchar(30),
    questions  varchar(50)[]
);
```

Infelizmente no SQL Server isso não é possível. Eu poderia fazer uma segunda tabela chamada `QuestionsForMyTable`:

```
CREATE TABLE QuestionsForMyTable (
    id_of_mytable   integer,
    question        varchar(50)
);
```

E ai fazer o devido relacionamento, mas ei eu caio na desgraça de ter que fazer mais um JOIN.
Isso realmente é o que me resta ou existe outra saída melhor?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo

Answer (score 2):

*"para não deixar a pergunta sem resposta.."*

Sim, se existe uma lista dentro de um objetos e isso será levado ao banco de dados, deve ser criada uma segunda tabela que conterá esses itens da lista; e a forma de se carregar o objeto *completo* será através de um `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
JOIN QuestionsForMyTable ON id = id_of_mytable
```

Segundo [definição do devmedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930), *"por meio dessa cláusula, os dados de uma tabela são usados para selecionar os dados pertencentes à outra tabela"*.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde,

Isto pode ser feito recorrendo a uma Computed Column que retorne os valores de uma outra tabela. Pode ser feito da forma descrita a seguir.

Criar e popular a tabela com os elementos para alimentar a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE QuestionsForMyTable 
(
    id_of_mytable   integer,
    question        varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO QuestionsForMyTable 
    SELECT 1, 'Question 1' UNION
    SELECT 1, 'Question 2'
```

Criar uma função que retorne os elementos desta tabela para um determinado Id:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue(@id int)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ret nvarchar(max)
    SET @ret = ''

    SELECT  @ret = @ret + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + question
    FROM    QuestionsForMyTable
    WHERE   id_of_mytable = @id

    RETURN @ret

END
```

Criar a tabela com a computed column baseada nesta função:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    id         integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name       varchar(30),
    questions  as dbo.GetValue(id)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable
    SELECT 1, 'First set of questions' UNION
    SELECT 2, 'Second set of questions'
```

No final, basta um select à Mytable para obtermos o resultado esperado.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Comment: (1) Funções do tipo escalar tornam o processo de execução da consulta mais lento; (2) Além disso, a solução acima cai no problema _quem nasceu primeiro: o ovo ou a galinha_, pois necessita que as questões já tenham sido previamente incluídas. Ora, como inserir as questões se o objeto principal ainda não existe?!

Comment: Sim, uma solução deste tipo não pode ser aplicado a grandes volumes de dados, iria ficar lento. Quanto ao resto, tudo tem a ver com a arquitetura montada, ter ou não dados numa ou noutra tabela não impede o seu funcionamento. Penso que, aqui, o únicio problema pode ser mesmo a lentidão com grandes volumes de dados.